# how to find all the select elements that have changed?

Tags: javascript

let's say I have a form that contains several "select" element that the User can choose.
when ready to submit, I need to find all the "select" that have changed.
how can I do it?

for example:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="a"/>
    <select name="b">...</select>
    <select name="c">...</select>
    <select name="d">...</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, something like this should work:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $(this).addClass('changed');
});

$('form').submit(function() {
    var changed_selects = $('select.changed');
    // do what you want with the changed selects
});
```

Comment: definitely like this solution better than what I proposed, but I would recommend adding in a pure JavaScript solution b/c the OP didn't mention jQuery.

Comment: And what if the `select`'s value is changed back to the one originally marked `selected`?

Comment: The question provides no context. It may or may not be relevant, this code assumes it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I would take advantage of the `defaultSelected` property on [HTMLOptionElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLOptionElement) instead of trying to keep track of `select`s that have changed:

```
form.onsubmit = function() {
    var selects = form.getElementsByTagName("select")
        , i
        , changedSelects = []
        , selected
        , select;

    /* Iterate over all selects in the form: */
    for (i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
        select = selects[i];
        /* Get the currently selected <option> element: */
        selected = select[select.selectedIndex];

        /* Determine if the currently selected option is the one selected by default: */
        if (!selected.defaultSelected) {
            changedSelects.push(select);
        }
    }

    alert(changedSelects.length);
}
```

You can iterate over all of the `select` elements on your form, determine if the selected option is the one that was selected by default, and push each one whose selected option wasn't the default into an array.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/abFr3/

Comment: Options will only have the defaultSelected property set to true if the element has the selected attribute or the property has been set programatically.

Comment: @RobG: Yes, that's a good point. I just assumed "selects changed" meant there was an option selected by default, but I don't think that's always the case.

Answer (score 0):

You could register an event listener (using [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onchange), etc.) to determine if any changes were made.

Alternatively, you could keep a private copy of all of the previous values, then run a comparison before submit to check for changes.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
var selectedVal =  $("select[name='a'] option:selected").val();
//check this with your default selected val
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the `onchange` event listener to each `<select>` element. When the event is triggered, you can store the actual elements in an a temporary array and reference it later when you are ready to submit. Note that the array can hold the actual DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify what you mean by "the select have changed".

If you mean have changed from their default value, then you should have one option on each select (usually the first) set as the default selected option. Then you can iterate over the selects and see if the option with the selected attribute (or where the defaultSelected property is true) is the selected option, e.g.

```
<script>
function anyChanged(){
    var select, selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

    for (var i=0, iLen=selects.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      select = selects[i];

      if (!select.options[select.selectedIndex].defaultSelected) {
        // the selected option isn't the default
        alert('select ' + (select.id || select.name) + ' changed');
      }
    }
 }
</script>

<select name="one">
  <option selected>one
  <option>two
  <option>three
</select>

<button onclick="anyChanged()">Check</button>
```

However, if you want to see if the user has changed the selected option based on some other logic, you need to say what it is.